# How are customs seperated in Athens meaning intra and extra schengen

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, athens

When arriving from Terminal B which is for all Schengen flights where are you directed to. I don't think the EU Customs Agreement has nothing to do with this.

EDIT: What I meant is how are they directed toward the currect arrival area meaning can't someone from Terminal A just go through the wrong channel.

Comment: http://www.athensflights.gr/images/arrival-terminal.pdf

Comment: Customs doesn't care about Schengen. There are Schengen countries (such as Norway) that are outside the EU customs union -- and countries _in_ the EU customs zone that are not in Schengen (such as Ireland). What customs looks for is the green stripes on the side of baggage tags from EU countries.

Comment: @HenningMakholm It seems like this would cause a loophole. Somebody comes in from a extra-EUCU flight with expensive goods and hands them to a intra-EUCU passenger before crossing customs.

Comment: @user71659 random checks are still done.

Comment: A small note: It happened to me that passengers from Switzerland (in Schengen) were checked on transfer path, and redirected to the exit (so a new passport check and hand baggage scan).

Comment: @user71659 most countries care a lot more amount immigration (passport control) than about customs. Consider the fact that most people that need to will have their ID and other travel documents checked, while customs checks are performed only on a small sample of passengers.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Random checks wouldn't help because unless they caught the handover (or the goods need tax stamps like cigarettes) they wouldn't know that the goods were not properly imported into the EUCU.

Comment: @user71659: it works because the risk is very high. It is not just "forgetting" to declare. How you describe it is criminal deception. Custom could ask you about the origin, and one should be a good liar (but probably one would give the truth, so just getting a fine) and getting in a watch list. The purpose of custom is to avoid "illicit competition" from foreign stuffs, not to catch every single illicit import. So private people will confess, criminals will possibly be caught in future. Do not think customs are so naive (it is very mathematical driven, by risks)

Comment: When you post a question on this site you agree to leave it up for future use by other people. So please do not delete or deface questions.